# Undefined variable: class yii2

Tags: php

When I insert this code in gridview, there is error `Undefined variable: class`

```
'value' => 'order_customFields_delivery_method',
            'contentOptions' => function ($data)
            {
                if ($data['order_customFields_delivery_method'] == 'Euro')

                {
                    $class = 'style';
                }

                return  [$class => 'font-weight: bold;'];}
        ],
```

In what can be a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When condition inside `if` is not met `$class` is not set but you try to use it anyway.

Comment: What do you mean? I try different variants, but still error.

Comment: When `$data['order_customFields_delivery_method']` is something different from `Euro` variable `$class` is undefined so trying to use it inside the array gives you error.